# In below scenario, what's the best practice

Tags: payment

If I am making a payment and the first screen shows the amount and asks for card details, I move to the next screen and my amount has been updated with transaction fee based on card type. Is it good practice. Should the actual amount + fees and total of both be together one first screen? Also, should we be transparent with which card type incur what percent of fees?

Comment: FYI in future, I would suggest summarising whatever problem you are trying to solve in the title of the question (your current title only tells us that you're seeking "best practice" on an unknown "scenario"). You'll likely get a better response rate if users know what it is they are about to click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something that would need to be A/B tested. But I’m my opinion you’re better off being transparent and showing the fee up front if your system allows it. It’s likely that a surprise fee will frustrate users and cause abandonment. How big of an issue will it be? I have no idea.

If you aren’t able to provide an accurate fee before the credit card is entered, then at least show the fee as TBD in the order summary. That way they know it’s coming.

Again, there’s no right or wrong answer here. It should be tested. But I would err on the side of being transparent and honest with issues like these.